# Failed to load Analytics native module

Tags: react-native, firebase-analytics, segment

I'm trying to use Segment for analytics on my React Native app. I want it to work for both Android and iOs. This issue persists on both OS's.

I installed the NPM library as explained [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react-native#installation) by doing:

```
yarn add @segment/analytics-react-native
yarn react-native link
```

Expected behaviour: I'm able to use analytics in the app

Actual behaviour: an error is thrown with message "Failed to load Analytics native module"

Code: (i do this in App.tsx/componentDidMount)

```
import Segment from '@segment/analytics-react-native';
import FirebaseAnalytics from '@segment/analytics-react-native-firebase'

Segment.setup(keys.segment.writeKey, {
  recordScreenViews: true,
  trackAppLifecycleEvents: true,
  trackAttributionData: true,
  using: [FirebaseAnalytics]
})
```

This is pretty much what they use in the documents. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. One thing to note is that I'm using Expo, not plain react-native.

I've tried solutions mentioned [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react-native/issues/19) and [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react-native/issues/19) but to no avail.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Im having the same problem.

Comment: @BrenoMazieiro i think i just ended up messing around with version numbers until i found one that works.

Comment: ive updated to "expo": "^42.0.0", and now its working, but i had a lot of refactorings in my code due to that, but anyway... its working now. =) Thanks!

Comment: yeah i remember it being a weird fix. i was just trying things till it worked, but glad it worked out for you :) @BrenoMazieiro

Comment: what was the solution for this issue?